# How to bind Navigation Property for Entity

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core

Ef Core 5.0.1

IQueryable.ToList entity Mapping with Include navigation property

When i trace sql query , it returns proper result,

but when i see entity mapping , for some record navingation property bind correctly, but for other it is not binding,

Entity :- Department
Navigation Property :- CreatedByUser

It is returning 5 department

in that 4 rows binding CreatedByUser where as 1 row binding as null even though CreatedByUserId is there

Can any one explain how actual that works ? From Query to Object binding ?

Comment: Please describe your problem in detail with the code.

Comment: @Yinqiu Problem is When i am trying to fetch Details using IQueryable with Include , it is not properly binding , so i want to understand , when performing IQueryable.ToList(), it makes call to database and how it bind with objects back to entity ? because for some rows it bind navigation property properly.

Comment: You have to ensure that  your relations are configured properly

Comment: @TimurUmerov if relationship is wrong , can there be possibility , if there are 5 records, it is binding for 3 records correctly but for 2 it doesn't.

Comment: There is always a possibility. 
Can you provide code you are using to configure `Department` Navigation property, the linq query you are using and a response you are getting from db (raw, not mapped)?

Comment: @TimurUmerov From DB Query result i get specific id value say LastModifierUserId but when it gets map to Entity column it is empty not sure why, and as i have already mentioned it confuse me because 7 records are there with each of have LastModifierUserId has some value but when it bind to entity it for some rows LastModifierUserId is null (LastModifierUserId is nullable)

Comment: `modelBuilder.Entity<Entity>()
              .HasOne(u => u.CreatorUser)
              .WithOne()
              .HasForeignKey<Entity>(x => x.CreatorUserId)
              .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientCascade);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Entity>()
                  .HasOne(u => u.LastModifierUser)
                  .WithOne()
                  .HasForeignKey<Entity>(x => x.LastModifierUserId);`

Comment: So after so many work around found that virtual keyword was missing from navigation property but still not sure why some data was binding and some doesnt